# How do I find the following? [Random Variables]

Tags: probability, random-variables

$U-$uniform distribution.
$X=U(0,1), Y=U(0,1),Z=\sqrt{1+(X-Y)^2}$ 
Find $F(z)-$function of distribution.
What I've done so far:

$\phi(x,y)=\{1,(x,y)\in(0,1) \times (0,1); 0, $otherwise$\}$

$F(z)=P\{Z<z\}=P\{ X-\sqrt{z^2-1}<Y<X+\sqrt{z^2-1}\}=**1-z^2+2\sqrt{z^2-1}**,1<z<\sqrt2$

How did they arrive at the highlighted? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a uniform distribution so we don't need to mess with integration, just measure the proportionate area of the event against the support (the unit square).

$\{\langle X, Y\rangle\in (0;1)^2 : X−\sqrt{z^2-1}<Y<X+\sqrt{z^2−1}\}$ is the section of the unit square between the lines $y=x-\sqrt{z^2-1}$ and $y=x+\sqrt{z^2-1}$.

That is also section of the unit square *excluding* the triangles above and below those lines.  So we can more easily use the Law of Complements to evaluate the required probability.

Those right triangles each have height and width of $(1-\sqrt{z^2-1})$ , thus area of $\tfrac 1 2(1-\sqrt{z^2-1})^2$ (and there are *two* of them).

So the required probability is: $1-(1-\sqrt{z^2-1})^2$ .

The rest is algebra.